# TFS | unable to organize source project's files into multiple new folders

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to organize TFS project to apply new structure

I moved the files from parent folder A to subfolders B C D
but the msg appear

`was not renamed in the source control database because there is already an item with this name in the destination folder`

and any one get the latest version will face duplicated files error

[image: Error Msg when moving files]

What you suggested solution to this issue
BTW I have too many files and folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TFS there are two kinds of moving files. I have crated a sample for both :

Local Workspace (window exploer) directly move/drag file

---

1. In the disk my workspace, I'm going to move *2.PNG* to *Main-branch*

   ```
   folder
   ```

[image]

2. Then we could check what TFS detects in VS. One with add(in new

   place), one with delete(in old place) in Promote Candidate Changes.

   [image]
3. You need to check in both the add and delete ( promote first). Finally

   you will get what you want both server and local.

**Move a file in solution explorer directly**

---

1. In the solution explorer , I'm going to move *1.PNG* to *Main

   folder* by right click and select move.

[image]

2. You will get a pending change with **rename** status directly and

   not any Promote Candidate Changes.

   [image]
3. Then we could check our local workspace, you will see 1.PNG is

   **automatically deleted in the workspace folder** even though you haven't check in changes. Finally checking pending

   changes, everything is fine and clean.

   [image]

---

Back to your error: `xx was not renamed in the source control database because there is already an item with this name in the destination folder`

You should be using way 2, so there was already some files with same name in parent folder A and subfolders B C D

The solution should be deleting duplicate files in B C D.

---

It's better to not move files frequently in TFS server folder, this will also **mess up the history info**.

Comment: It's only a workaround isn't is? Normally it should be enough to move files in the Solution Explorer and VS should do the rest. It seems that VS 2019 (at least 16.7.3) does not work well with projects with the new .csproj format and TFS.